# Matlab - regular expression, excluding a substring

Tags: regex, matlab

How do I search a sequence for a certain match not containing a certain substring? As in wanting to search an RNA sequence starting with `CG` and not containing `AG` in the middle and then ending with it? When I run

```
regexp(mRNA, 'GU\w+[^AG]AG');
```

it gives me the location of matches that dont contain either `A` or `G` in the middle, and not the `AG` substring. Would really appreciate the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression should work fine:

```
^(?!GC.*AG.*AG)CG.*AG$
```

It uses a negative lookahead assertion (for more information read [this page](http://regular-expressions.mobi/lookaround.html?wlr=1)). Visit [this link](https://regex101.com/r/JjL0PZ/3) for a full working demo.

If you aren't sure that your strings contain only uppercase characters, you can replace `regexp` with `regexpi`, which performs a case-insensitive matching. Example:

```
mRNA = {
 'CGUUAG'
 'CGCGUCAG'
 'AGUCGUAG'
 'CGAGAG'
 'UUAGAGCUUAGC'
 'CGCGCGAG'
 'CGAG'
 'AAGCCU'
 'GACU'
};

regexpi(mRNA,'^(?!CG.*AG.*AG)CG.*AG$')

ans =
      [1]
      [1]
      []
      []
      []
      [1]
      [1]
      []
      []
```